# How would I implement the C bitwise operators in Z3-PY?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, z3, z3py

I'd like to be able to implement the following rule to my `Solver` s, where the '^' and '&' operators are the 'or' and 'and' from C. `input_list` is a 100 element `IntVector`:

```
s.add(
((input_list[6] ^ input_list[10]) & 0xF) +
((input_list[3] + input_list[5] - 25) ^ (3*input_list[99])) == 73)
```

Running this code gives a type error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'ArithRef' and 'ArithRef'
```

Replacing the '^' and '&' with Z3's boolean operators as follows:

```
s.add(
(And(Or(input_list[6],input_list[10]),0xF) +
 Or((input_list[3] + input_list[5] - 25), (3*input_list[99]))) == 73)
```

gives this error:

```
z3.z3types.Z3Exception: b'Sort mismatch at argument #1 for function (declare-fun or (Bool Bool) Bool) supplied sort is Int'
```

How can I represent this operation as a rule for the z3 solver?

Comment: Note that `^` is xor in C. Or is `|`

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the `Int` type in SMTLib (and z3) is a full-blown mathematical integer. It does not have any "bits," nor it is bounded by any means. That is, it is not something you can do bit-wise operations on. You haven't given actual fully executable code, but here's a simpler example illustrating the error you're getting:

```py
from z3 import *

x, y = Ints('x y')

s = Solver()
s.add(x ^ y == 0)
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

For the above code, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 6, in <module>
    s.add(x ^ y == 0)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'ArithRef' and 'ArithRef'
```

(The lists or vectors etc. are irrelevant for this problem; so I'm eliding those.)

In C, when you use the `int` type, it actually refers to a machine integer, i.e., it has a fixed-width. Typically 64 bits on most machines, but it depends on the architecture you're using. So, to do the same in z3, you have to use what's known as a bit-vector and specify exactly how wide you want those bit-vectors to be.

Below is the same code, but this time with 32-bit machine arithmetic:

```py
from z3 import *

x, y = BitVecs('x y', 32)

s = Solver()
s.add(x ^ y == 0)
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

Now I get:

```
sat
[y = 0, x = 0]
```

You can read more about bit-precise arithmetic in z3 here: https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm